# compact and closed set problem

Tags: compactness

2. Let {Ωα : α ∈ I} be an arbitrary family of closed sets Ωα ⊆R^d with an index set I.

   (a) Prove that
   ⋂Ωα is a closed set. [7]

   (b) Set d = 2 and show by construction of a counterexample that ⋃ Ωα is not necessarily closed. [2]

I understand the definitions of closed sets (contains all of its limit points) and that if a set is compact then it is closed but cant seem to work this out.

Comment: Can you show that the intersection of *two* closed sets is closed?

Comment: is the intersection of two closed sets the empty set which is closed?

Comment: also, de morgans law has bee mentioned, is this relevant?

Answer (score 0):

(I). Let $F$ be a family of closed subsets of $\Bbb R^n.$

Let $\sigma=(p_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ be any  convergent sequence of members of $\cap F,$   converging to $p.$ Then for each $f\in F,$ all the members of $\sigma$ belong to $f,$ and $f$ is closed, so $p\in F.$ Since $p$ belongs to every member of $F,$ therefore $p$ belongs to $\cap F.$

(II). If $U$  is any non-closed subset of $\Bbb R^n,$  consider that $F=\{\{p\}:p\in U\}$ is a family of closed sets of $\Bbb R^n$ but $\cup F =U$ is not closed.